# Going through a list in pairs, except for first element, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list `myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and some `function` that is not relevant to the current problem. I want to access the list in pairs, such as:

```
value['a'] = function(myList[:1])
value['b'] = function(myList[:2]) - function(myList[:1])
value['c'] = function(myList[:3]) - function(myList[:2])
...
value['e'] = function(myList) - function(myList[:len(myList)-1])
```

where `value` can be a dictionary.

To be more explicit, the above code should look like:

```
value['a'] = function(['a'])
value['b'] = function(['a', 'b']) - function(['a'])
value['c'] = function(['a', 'b', 'c']) - function(['a', 'b'])
...
value['e'] = function(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) - function(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

I am trying to do this with a simple for loop:

```
value = {}
for idx in range(len(myList)):
   if not value[myList[idx]]:
      value[myList[idx]] = function[myList[:idx]] - function[myList[:idx-1]]
   else:
      temp = function[myList[:idx]] - function[myList[:idx-1]]
      value[myList[idx]] += [temp]   # end-up with a list of values for every element.
```

I have two problems with this:

1. It does not work well for the beginning and end of the list.
2. The code looks very cumbersome and I am wondering if there is a more pythonic way of writing it.

Comment: `values = [function(myList[0])] + [function(myList[:idx]) - function(myList[:idx - 1]) for idx in range(1, len(myList))]`

Comment: @OlvinRoght, could you please elaborate and add it as an answer ?

Comment: Added it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why do you want to put results into `dict` with `int` keys, starting from `1`. It's `list` representation using `dict` which I find useless in that case (*maybe you need it in future code, I don't know*).

To form a list with results you can use next list comprehension:

```
values = [function(myList[0])] + [function(myList[:idx]) - function(myList[:idx - 1]) for idx in range(2, len(myList) + 1)]
```

This is shortened (*and slightly more efficient*) version of next code:

```
values = [function(myList[0])]
for idx in range(2, len(myList) + 1): # range(1, len(myList))
    first_slice = myList[: idx]       # myList[: idx + 1]
    second_slice = myList[: idx - 1]  # myList[: idx]
    values.append(function(first_slice) - function(second_slice))
```

If you still want to get results in `dict`, you can create it using next code:

```
dict_result = dict(zip(range(1, len(values) + 1), values))
```

Comment: for the last line you can also use `dict_result = {index:value for index, value in enumerate(values, 1)]`

Comment: Sorry, I now realize there was an error in my question. The keys in my dictionary are not int keys, they are the elements of the original list. Fixed the question now.

Comment: You don't cache the function result, then you take twice as time as my response + possible side effects

Comment: @hl037_, I'm not pretending to write most efficient solution and probably it's not needed.

Comment: @Qubix, which element do you want to set as a key? Value is formed from difference between result of functions which work with list slices – _

Comment: key should be the 'a', 'b' ... the values should be the differences of the functions

Answer (score 0):

certainly most efficient way :

```
# Test data
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# Your `function`
def f(args):
  print(args)
  return len(args)


# BEGIN OF ANSWER
from itertools import accumulate

#prev = accumulated value (to cache previous call to f) while returning the current value too, that is used in the dict comprehension
def func(prev, x):
  cur = f(x)
  val, prev_x = prev
  return cur - prev_x, cur

#cache the initial call
init = f( [ l[0] ])
value = dict(
  zip(
    l,
    accumulate(
      ( l[:k] for k in range(1, len(l)) ),
      func,
      initial=(init, init)
    )
  )
)
```

**EDIT** the previous one is for python 3.8. for python < 3.8, then accumulate has no `initial` keyword argument. Thus, you have to stick with reduce hacks...

```
# Test data
l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
# Your function
def f(args):
    print(args)
    return len(args)


# BEGIN OF ANSWER
from functools import reduce

# reduce function : prev = (list_of_final_values, previous function call result)
def func(prev, x):
  cur = f(x)
  vals, prev_x = prev
  vals.append(cur - prev_x)
  return vals, cur

# initial value cached too
init = f( [ l[0] ])
value = dict(
  zip( l,
    reduce(
      func,
      ( l[:k] for k in range(1, len(l)) ),
      ([init], init)
    )[0]
  )
)
```

...Same result, except it's not lazy...

References :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Comment: TypeError: accumulate() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: which python version ?

Comment: 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) 
[GCC 7.3.0]

Comment: erf, indeed, it's only in 3.8 they added the initial param, my bad, I will propose a 3.7 way then :) https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate

Comment: @Qubix  added a 3.3 < python < 3.8 version , and I also updated for the question modification about the dict key

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have a list

```
lis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

lis[:2] will give you [1, 2], i.e., one index less than the parameter passed - 0th and 1st index element, NOT the 2nd element. So, your requirement of "pairing" will not be fulfilled by

```
function(lis[:2]) - function(lis[:1])
```

as this will only give the second element of the list. This answers your first question of "not working well with the beginning and end of the list"
For the second part of your question, what I can infer from your question is that you want to access the list as {'a':'b', 'c':'d', 'e':'f'}. For this,

```
myDict = {}
for i in range(0, len(myList), 2):
  myDict.update({myList[i] : myList[i + 1]})
```

If you want to access the list as {'a':'b', 'b':'c', 'c':'d', 'd':'e', 'e':'f'}, do

```
myDict = {}
for i in range(0, len(myList)):
    if i != len(myList) - 1:
        myDict.update({myList[i] : myList[i + 1]})
```